# How to integrate payumoney payment gateway with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, payumoney

Included "gem 'active_merchant_payu_in'" in Gemfile. Getting this error while bundle install

```
/home/waheguru/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/active_merchant_payu_in-0.0.1/lib/active_merchant_payu_in.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_merchant/billing/integrations (LoadError)
```

Comment: Did you get the solution veerji?

Comment: My experience while integrating PayuMoney or PayuBiz payment gateway with ROR application. 

There are gems to integrate PayuBiz but they all are not working. So I included payu_form with my application and passing values dynamically. 
Here is that form
https://github.com/payu-india/PayU-Integration-Kit-ROR/blob/master/app/views/carts/show.html.erb

and it works.. I even spoke with couple of ROR-developers and they all did same. 

In payment_form_for_payu form we need to specify key and salt-key.

Comment: Thankyou very much for responding, where is that form method present?

Comment: please try this https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4f9d8741103df5bfaf46

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out.

Comment: It doesn't solve problem for PayuMoney, with this form PayuMoney is just a one payment method in a list.

Comment: Tried all the possible ways which support guys provided but none worked except this. Still searching for better alternates(please share if u find any).

Comment: @KJ_kaka have you got any exact solution for this issue ?

Comment: @VishalNagda - I am still looking/searching for the solution.

Answer (score -4):

THIS FORM AND CALL BACK METHOD IS WORKING GOOD PAYU MONEY INTEGRATION kit....

Just add the form on cart show page which will create PayUmoney button  and pass the required parms value to it...

Also able to successfully test  payment and callback from PayUmoney after using below test credit card.

Test Card Numbers
You can do transactions against a PAYU money
 account in test mode using the following test card numbers.

Mastercard
card number 5123456789012346
expiry date  0517 (MMYY)
csc/cvv  100

Visa
card number  4987654321098769
expiry date  0517 (MMYY)
csc/cvv  100

So to test an approved Mastercard you would enter details as below

card number  5123456789012346
expiry date  0517 (MMYY)
purchase amount $1.00

And to test an insufficient funds Mastercard response you would enter details as below

card number  5123456789012346
expiry date  0517 (MMYY)
purchase amount $1.51

As my first post on stack Overflow I used the link and got - 3 downvotes and after proper rnd came to know about rotlink so copy and paste the content itself...

THANKS KJ_KAKA

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).